# 503 error DynamoDB local with boto3

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto, boto3, http-proxy

I tried using the basic example in the aws documentation, by starting dynamoDB as follows.

`java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb`

And it produces the output 

`Initializing DynamoDB Local with the following configuration:
Port:   8000
InMemory:   false
DbPath: null
SharedDb:   true
shouldDelayTransientStatuses:   false
CorsParams: *`

The example python code is as follows.

```
from __future__ import print_function # Python 2/3 compatibility
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2',endpoint_url='http://localhost:8000')


table = dynamodb.create_table(
    TableName='Movies',
    KeySchema=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'year',
            'KeyType': 'HASH'  #Partition key
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'title',
            'KeyType': 'RANGE'  #Sort key
        }
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'year',
            'AttributeType': 'N'
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'title',
            'AttributeType': 'S'
        },

    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput={
        'ReadCapacityUnits': 10,
        'WriteCapacityUnits': 10
    }
)

print("Table status:", table.table_status)
```

But I get the output :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 32, in <module>
    'WriteCapacityUnits': 10
  File "/home/janga/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 520, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/janga/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 83, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(**params)
  File "/home/janga/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 251, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/janga/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 537, in _make_api_call
    raise ClientError(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (503) when calling the CreateTable operation (reached max retries: 9): <HTML><TITLE>503 Service Unavailable</TITLE>
<H1>503 Service Unavailable</H1>
Failed to connect to server <B>localhost</B></HTML>
```

I couldn't find any solution anywhere for this issue. 
The only reason I can think of is, that I am on a university network which runs behind a proxy server. But I can't find any solution for that.
Please help.

Comment: Are you sure the service that you started is running? Try running `netstat -anlp | grep 8000`

Comment: @L-Jones9. yes I am.tcp6       0      0 :::8000                 :::*                    LISTEN      11370/java

Comment: And just to make sure, you can actually `ping localhost` and your loopback is working? (I'm only asking because you mentioned it could possibly be your network.)

Comment: It is working, but another issue is that a background application runs an apache server on localhost:80 . So the loopback may be from that.

Comment: @L-Jones9 But I used `telnet localhost 8000`, and it does get connected.

Comment: are you sure there's nothing else running on the port 8000? I have an experience I can run (eg.) Django's runserver on 8000 and spawning Dynamo at the same port without it reporting an error.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko I changed the port to 8888, and the problem still exists.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is to play with the actual python library that is doing the connecting (which you should be able to figure out from the stacktrace). It is almost certainly a connection issue to your localhost.